# Best preposition for “ part time”

Tags: prepositions

> I had to work in//as // for part-time while I was studying in the university.

Which preposition should I use in sentence above? Should I say “ work in part-time” or “work as part-time”or “work for part-time” ?I try to understand how “ part time is used as an adverb?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You use **part-time** as the adverb:

- I had to **work part-time** while I was studying at the university

At least in the UK, we are usually *at university*.

For this sentence it would be ungrammatical to add "in/as/for".  There are similar sentences which have them:

- I was in part-time work while ...
- I worked as a part-time waiter while ...
- I had to work for part of the time while ...

Comment: My first thought was your second "similar" example lacks an article. It was only when I was contemplating editing it in *(I worked as **a** part-time waiter)* that I realised it was at least "credible" without the article. It's a bit unlikely though - adjectival "part-time" is syntactically irrelevant, and few people would say *He worked as waiter at McDonalds over Christmas*.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica thanks, it was a typo, I'd meant "a part-time waiter" which is I agree the more usual phrase.

Comment: Haha. You and I might both know perfectly well that both versions are *possible* - but we also know that one is far more likely than the other. Which some ELL users might not realise, so it was a good idea to make that edit, to avoid encouraging anyone to think the less common version might be "equally" valid / natural. I say that specifically because *some* users might not use articles like this in their own language, so they could be particularly likely to see, remember, and erroneously reproduce the article-less form, if that matches the way their own language works.